# Почему Timer работает только 2 раза?

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Задача таймера вызывать функцию каждые 7 минут, но почему-то таймер вызывается только 1 раз, прочитал что это связано с локальным объявлением таймера, но точно не понял в чем ошибка.

как мне сделать таймер, работающий до закрытия приложения?

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            textBox1.Text = InputValue();
            UpdateTimer();
        }
 private void UpdateTimer()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 420000;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Elapsed += Form1_Shown;
            timer.Start();           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте другой таймер `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Еще у вас бесконечная рекурсия с перезапусками таймера, который перезапускает сам себя. Вынесите то, что должно происходить в таймере в отдельный метод.

Для запуска процессов используйте лучше обработчик `Form.Load`, а не `Form.Shown`, чтобы к моменту показа пользователю форма цже была загружена полностью.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = InputValue();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => { textBox1.Text = InputValue(); };
    timer.Interval = 420000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

И нет, ваша проблема не связана с локальным объявлением, скорее с тем, что вы пытаетесь получить доступ к контролам из стороннего потока, там выбрасывается исключение при доступе к `textBox1` из стороннего потока, но так как оно происходит не в основном потоке и вы его никак не перехватываете с помощью `try-catch` - то соответственно и не видите. Поэтому лучше использовать именно таймер, который специально адаптирован для работы с UI Winforms.

Comment: А нет вероятности, что такой локальный таймер будет утилизирован `GC` в случайный момент времени? Или он хоть объявляется локально, но по сути штука всё-таки `GUI`-шная какая-то?

Comment: @CrazyElf нет верятности. GC умнее, чем кажется :)